# Do I need to recheck my baggage when transiting in AMS?

Tags: transit, ams, klm

I have a flight with KLM from Istanbul to Warsaw. The flight is with KLM.
Does anybody know where am I going to get my luggage? Is it Netherlands or Warsaw?

Comment: Is it a single booking or two separate tickets?

Comment: Single booking ..

Answer (score 11):

Ask at check-in but if nothing strange happens you will only get your luggage in Warsaw.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a single booking with KLM, or any airline, you will have to pick up your baggage at the baggage claim of the final airport of that booking, which for your upcoming journey is Warsaw. This means that the airline will arrange for each airport along the way to transfer your baggage to the next flight of your booking.

Conversely, if your journey consists of two separate bookings, even if it's with a single airline, you'll have to claim your baggage in between, but again, at the final airport of each booking.

Comment: This is overly simplified. Often, when your final leg is within a single country, you must clear customs with your luggage when you first land in that country. This is common for people flying to the USA or Canada. While that doesn't apply here, you have stated your rule too broadly.

Comment: I dont get it. What do you mean clear custom

Comment: So I will take my luggage in warsaw right?

Comment: In some cases it is possible to have your baggage checked all the way through to final destination, even on separate bookings. It requires a bit of manual work for the check in clerk, but it can be done

Comment: @Turkan To "clear customs" means to be checked by the customs/immigration services of a transit or destination country/area. For your journey that means a check to enter the Schengen area of with the Netherlands and Poland are both members. This is generally the part where, after you have claimed your baggage, you are asked to show your identification and if you have any imported goods to declare.

Comment: @KateGregory That makes sense. Not to prove you wrong, but as a counterexample for every single journey like that I've been on, I had to go through immigration, but my baggage was transferred for me. This might have been because I used to depart from AMS and these flights were to the USA, which has managed to convince AMS (and many other airports) to deploy additional USA-specific checks prior to departure